# MongoDB range query with a sort - how to speed up?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, nosql, mongodb-query, query-performance

I have a query which is routinely taking around 30 seconds to run for a collection with 1 million documents. This query is to form part of a search engine, where the requirement is that every search completes in less than 5 seconds. Using a simplified example here (the actual docs has embedded documents and other attributes), let's say I have the following:

**1 millions docs** of a `Users` collections where each looks as follows:

```
{
  name: Dan,
  age: 30,
  followers: 400 
},
{ 
  name: Sally,
  age: 42,
  followers: 250
}
... etc
```

Now, lets I'm wanting to return the IDs of 10 users with a follower count between 200 and 300, sorted by age in descending order. This can be achieved with the following:

```
db.users.find({
  'followers': { $gt: 200, $lt: 300  },
}).
projection({ '_id': 1 }).
sort({ 'age': -1 }).
limit(10)
```

I have the following compound Index created, which `winningPlan` tells me is being used:

```
db.users.createIndex({ 'followed_by': -1, 'age': -1 })}
```

But this query is still taking ~30 seconds as it's having to examine thousands of docs, near equal to the amount of docs in this case that match the find query. I have experimented with different indexes (with different positions and sort orders) with no luck.

So my question is, **what else can I do to either reduce the number of documents examined with the query, or speed up the the process of having to examine the docs?**

The query is taking long both in production and on my local dev environment, somewhat ruling many network and hardware factors. `currentOp` shows that the query is not waiting for locks while running, or that there are any other queries running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like you have an incorrect index: `{ 'followed_by': -1, 'age': -1 }` for your query. You should have an index `{ 'followers': 1}` (but take into consideration cardinality of that field). But even with that index, you will need to do inmem sort. Anyway, it should be much faster in the way you have high cardinality because you will not need to scan the whole collection for filtering step as you do with index prefix `followed_by`.